# Can I take a flight one way to Israel?

Tags: us-citizens, israel, one-way

I’m an American citizen and my fiancé lives in Bethlehem, Palestine. I’m going to visit him and his family on September of this year. I want to spend one month with them. Is it possible to take a flight one way and then buy a flight home when I'm ready to return to America?

Comment: Regardless of validity/legality I have always found one-way flights to cost about the same as a return flight.

Comment: Have a look at an open ended airline ticket.

Comment: Note that coming to meet a Palestinian fiancé may get you relatively strictly, so be sure to obey requirements to the dot.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is with the airline letting you on the flight, not the border guard, although the border guard will be *very* interested in your travel to Palestine. However, if you are refused entry at the border, it will be for "security" and not over a ticket.

In theory, a return or onward ticket is required. In practice, over a couple years, only British Airways enforced the rule and did not let me board without one. Air Canada, TWA (now defunct, of course), and Lufthansa did not, perhaps others. (Eventually I had a work visa which made the issue irrelevant.)

Assuming you have some money on your credit card, do what I did. Be prepared to buy an expensive, fully-refundable return one-way ticket. And then, once in Israel, cash it in for the refund. British tried a rather interesting gimmick of selling me the ticket in GB pounds and refunding the same *number* in US dollars, but the credit card company helped me set them straight.

Gratuitous advice: also be prepared for a lengthy *exit* interview, including search, when leaving Israel, because of your personal connection to a Palestinian.